# Reintegrate feature branch into trunk & saving revisions

Tags: svn, merge

I'm new to svn and I'm a bit confused with reintegrate function.

When I started to develop new feature I created branch of my project. Then I committed some revisions and now I want to reintegrate it back to trunk. When I do this it appears like single commit in trunk branch. But I want to see all history of revisions of feature branch in my trunk. What I have to do for this? Maybe ‘Merge range of revisions’ will help? Or I have to store this feature branch forever to access it's history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done everything correctly. The reintegrate was exactly what you needed to do. Now, when you view the trunk's log make sure you include merged revisions in whatever Subversion client you are using. If you are using TortoiseSVN then there is a checkbox in the show log dialog box that toggles this behavior. By the way, the feature branch will be stored forever regardless. Deleting it only removes it from the head revision.

Comment: Thank you! And what I should do now with feature branch? What are the best practices?

Comment: I normally delete the feature branch when I am done so that it does not clutter my branches folder. Since it is only a logical deletion you can always resurrect it if you really want to.